# Php date() giving the wrong time after parsing

Tags: php, mysql

This is confusing as hell, here's the php I'm using:

```
<?php echo date('H:i D j, F',$j->date); ?>
```

This is what it gives me:

```
01:33 Thu 1, January
```

Which seems fine, until you look at the actual time that is being given ($j->date provides):

```
2010-06-12 21:12:23
```

Why is it giving me a January and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$j->date` **must** provide `date()` with a *standard unix timestamp*. take a look at the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). You might want to pass it through the [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function first.

```
<?php echo date('H:i D j, F', strtotime($j->date)); ?>
```

*`$j->date` output must be a US English date format*.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<?php echo date('H:i D j, F', strtotime($j->date)); ?>
```

The [`date()`](http://php.net/date) function only takes a timestamp, not a time string which you are trying to provide it. The [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) function will convert it for you before sending it to `date()`.

Comment: thank you, I think the guy above you stole your answer after you put it in :) accepting his.